# CSS Selector for Class without Specific ID

Tags: html, css

I have a series of elements with the class `.tab-pane` attached to it. They also each have their own unique ID. I am trying to select every `.tab-pane` that does not have the id `#home`. I have tried `.tab-pane:not#home{...}` but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Sample HTML

```
<div id="home"    class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="myself"  class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="contact" class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="resume"  class="tab-pane">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead:

```
.tab-pane:not(#home) {
    color: red;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wzVJ8/).

The thing that you're not-selecting appears within the parentheses of the `:not()` selector, rather than appearing as a 'chained' pseudo-selector.

In this specific case, since the element you want to have not-styled is the *first* element, you could also use the general-sibling combinator `~` to style subsequent siblings differently:

```
#home ~ .tab-pane {
    color: red;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wzVJ8/1/).

But this would, and *could*, only work if the differently-styled (or un-styled) element is the *first*, since CSS can only select elements that appear later in the DOM, either as subsequent siblings, or descendants, of earlier elements.

References:

- [Selectors Level 3, negation `:not()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant to do this:

```
.tab-pane:not(#home)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this (*this is just like regular expressions*)

```
.tab-pane:not([id^='home'])
 {/*your code*/}
```

If you want to not include the id's which start with letter "h" then try the below one:

```
.tab-pane:not([id^='h'])
{/*your code*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access each of the individual classes by either using `.tab-pane:eq(noOfClass)` selector

Check examples [here](http://sillythingsthatmatter.com/jQuery/jQuery_selectors.php)

OR You can also use :not selector `.tab-pane:not(#home)`

Comment: `eq()` would be a [tag:jquery] selector, whereas this question makes no mention of JavaScript, let alone jQuery. Now, CSS's `:nth-child()`/`:nth-of-type()` maybe..?